# How to divide one text file to couple text file depends on the string number in python

Tags: python

this is a code from martineu that i got before from my last question

```
with open('textfile.txt', 'rt') as inf:
    for linenum, line in enumerate(inf, start=1):
        filename = 'string {}.txt'.format(linenum)
        with open(filename, 'wt') as outf:
            outf.write(line)
```

this will print only one line. next line it will make a new txt file

in textfile.txt

```
string 1
this is my pen
this is my book
string 2
this is my phone
this is my ...
```

will divide to a couple of textfiles like this

string 1 in string 1.txt

this is my pen in string 2.txt

this is my book in string 3.txt

string 2 in string 4.txt

this is my phone in string 5.txt

so on..

But i need the one like this

string 1.txt

```
this is my pen
this is my book
```

string 2.txt

```
this is my phone
this is my ...
```

so on until string n+1

I thinking change the 'linenum'. But i don't have idea..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the most bruteforce method of solving .... Hope it helps

```
linenum = 1
filename = ''
with open('textfile.txt', 'rt') as inf:
for line in (inf):
    if 'string 'in line:
        filename = 'string {}.txt'.format(linenum)
        open(filename,'w')
        linenum+=1
        continue
    with open(filename, 'a') as outf:
        outf.write(line)
```

Comment: o yeah another question. i just recognize if i input string above 'string 1' in textfile.txt. for example i input the author above 'string 1'. the code will print error because the string must be print. so how i can remove the author string that i don't needed?

Comment: @stevanusgiri Just loop till you find the string that you want to print. Then start printing those lines, which are required.